# Custom Voice When we call

Tags: ios, ios6, phone-call

**I don't know if i am exceeding the limitations of expecting something at this level.**
Can i have a CustomVoice when i call someone.
For Eg.: if I Press a Button **CallUser** which would make a call to the specified number, when the user accepts/receives the call, he/she should be able to hear/listen a Custom Voice in the form of some message, kind of stuff, but i wont be speaking a word.

Please let me know if i am not clear.

**Feedbacks Welcomed.**

Thank You.
Best Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as a developers on iOS you can not interact with the telephone. So you will not be able to  have some kind of text to speech engine to do the call for you.

You might be able to do this if you develop your own VOIP client, since then you have full control over the call.